# Beautiful Soup - Nested table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am first going to point out that I am new to all of this but struggling with trying to get to a nested tables cells.

Here is the square footage field I am trying to get to down around line 282: view-source:http://services.wakegov.com/realestate/Account.asp?id=0355891

```
'square_feet': soup.findAll('table')[10].findAll('tr')[15].get_text().strip(),
```

The error I receive is:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more readable and easy approach would be to rely on the parameter label - in other words, find an element by text, get the parent `td` element and find the next `td` sibling element, e.g:

```
soup.find(text="Heated Area").find_parent('td').find_next_sibling("td").get_text()
```